# Append markup string to a tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, markup

Is it possible to set markup as tag content (akin to setting `innerHtml` in JavaScript)?

For the sake of example, let's say I want to add 10 `<a>` elements to a `<div>`, but have them separated with a comma:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(<<some document here>>)

a_tags = ["<a>1</a>", "<a>2</a>", ...] # list of strings
div = soup.new_tag("div")
a_str = ",".join(a_tags)
```

Using `div.append(a_str)` escapes `<` and `>` into `&lt;` and `&gt;`, so I end up with

```
<div> &lt;a1&gt; 1 &lt;/a&gt; ... </div>
```

`BeautifulSoup(a_str)` wraps this in `<html>`, and I see getting the tree out of it as an inelegant hack.

What to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to create a `BeautifulSoup` object out of your `HTML` string containing links:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup()
div = soup.new_tag('div')

a_tags = ["<a>1</a>", "<a>2</a>", "<a>3</a>", "<a>4</a>", "<a>5</a>"]
a_str = ",".join(a_tags)

div.append(BeautifulSoup(a_str, 'html.parser'))

soup.append(div)
print soup
```

Prints:

```
<div><a>1</a>,<a>2</a>,<a>3</a>,<a>4</a>,<a>5</a></div>
```

---

Alternative solution:

For each link create a `Tag` and append it to `div`. Also, append a comma after each link except last:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup()
div = soup.new_tag('div')

for x in xrange(1, 6):
    link = soup.new_tag('a')
    link.string = str(x)
    div.append(link)

    # do not append comma after the last element
    if x != 6:
        div.append(",")

soup.append(div)

print soup
```

Prints:

```
<div><a>1</a>,<a>2</a>,<a>3</a>,<a>4</a>,<a>5</a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's one solution, but ideally, I'd like a short one-liner to accomplish this task. And at this point I find doing something like `BeautifulSoup("<div>"+a_str+"</div>").div` to be the nicest looking one. Really unbelievable there's no more straightforward way to create _just_ the tag from markup.

Comment: @JanParowka I've edited the answer and included 2 options. Loading the tag from string using `BeautifulSoup(...)` is the easiest option.

Comment: Yeah, commented before your edit. That's what I've been looking for. Must have missed it in the doc, as I was expecting it to be in the modifying tree section. Awesome!